# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props') when trying to use callback between child and parent in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently having a problem when trying to send an action from a child element to its parent element. I want to change the state of the `MessagingContainer` when a thread is clicked to mark that thread as the active thread. So when the thread (`ThreadElement`) is clicked, it needs to send to its parent (`ThreadList`), which then sends to its parent (`MessagingContainer`) in order for the `Messaging Container` to update the state.

Firstly, is this the right approach, RE: state and modifying state?

Secondly, I can't seem to get this working. I'm getting a persistent error of `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props')`.

I've omitted the messages part of the code below so only the threads is visible.

```
var ThreadElement = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    console.log('ThreadElement');
    console.log(this.props);
    var threadParticipantsNames = this.props.thread.participants.map(function(participant) {
      var participantName;
      if (participant.user) {
        participantName = participant.user.metadata.first_name;
      } else {
        participantName = 'Anonymous';
      }

      return (
        <span key={participant.id}>
          {participantName}
        </span>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div key={this.props.thread.id} onClick={this.props.handleActiveThreadChange}>
        {threadParticipantsNames}
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var ThreadList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    console.log('ThreadList');
    console.log(this.props);
    var threadNodes = this.props.threads.map(function(thread) {
      return (
        <ThreadElement thread={thread} key={thread.id} handleActiveThreadChange={this.props.handleActiveThreadChange} />
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="threadList">
        {threadNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});


var MessagingContainer = React.createClass({
  handleActiveThreadChange: function() {
    console.log('MessagingContainer handleActiveThreadChange called.');
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      activeThread: 0,
      data: threadsJSON
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    console.log('MessagingContainer');
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <ThreadList threads={this.state.data.threads} handleActiveThreadChange={this.handleActiveThreadChange} />
        <MessageList thread={this.state.data.threads[this.state.activeThread]} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

The console gives the below output, if that helps. The `MessagingContainer` and `ThreadList` console.log()s seem to work, so does this suggest the issue is in the `ThreadElement` class?

```
[Log]   MessagingContainer
[Log]   {}
[Log]   ThreadList
[Log]   {threads: Array, handleActiveThreadChange: function}
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, I think the problem is your `.map` function in the `ThreadList` component. Your context has changed for `this` since you're inside the map function. You should use `.bind` or a local `that = this` variable to save the right context:

```
var threadNodes = this.props.threads.map(function(thread) {
  return (
    <ThreadElement thread={thread} key={thread.id} handleActiveThreadChange={this.props.handleActiveThreadChange} />
  );
}).bind(this);
```

or

```
var that = this;
var threadNodes = this.props.threads.map(function(thread) {
  return (
    <ThreadElement thread={thread} key={thread.id} handleActiveThreadChange={that.props.handleActiveThreadChange} />
  );
});
```

Comment: The second suggestion (the local variable) works perfectly — thanks! I tried the first one, but it still gave the error as before. Any thoughts on why this might be? (Just out of curiosity.)